# Why does FluentIterable.first() throw NPE when the first element is null

Tags: guava

Here is the method description for  [`FluentIterable.first()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#first()).

It throws a NPE but not return `Optional.absent()` when the first element is null.

I think it makes `FluentIterable` influent, and `Optional` as the return value gives me an impression that it's totally safe.

I wonder why? Thanks.

Comment: The `Optional` is meant to be used to indicate the absence of a first element - in other words, that the sequence was empty. I suspect the general answer is that `FluentIterable` is designed for sequences of non-null values.

Comment: We have `isEmpty()` to know if  the sequence is empty. And nope, you can do `filter()` with `Predicates.notNull()`. See description for `firstMatch()`.

Comment: Yes, you *can* use `isEmpty` to know if the sequence is empty - but it would require iterating again, which may not always give the same results. Note that while you can use `filter` with `notNull`, `firstMatch` with a nullity predicate has the same sort of warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [documented behavior](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#first()):

> ```
> public final Optional<E> first()
> ```
>
> Returns an `Optional` containing the first element in this fluent iterable. If the iterable is empty, `Optional.absent()` is returned.
>
> Throws:
>   `NullPointerException` - if the first element is `null`; **if this is a possibility, use `iterator().next()` or `Iterables.getFirst(java.lang.Iterable<? extends T>, T)` instead**.

Emphasis is mine, as a workaround follow the suggestions above. Generally, [Guava's collections are null-hostile](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

In this particular case, NPE is thrown to avoid ambiguity, because `Optional.absent()` is returned when *iterable is empty*, not when first element is `null`.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, is it better to use `isEmpty()`?

Comment: In your case (if you have an `Iterable` containing null values and want to fetch first value) what do you want to have as a result when: a) first element is `null` b) iterable is empty? This is *the* ambiguity you have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from method code below, `FluentIterable.first` is not implemented to handle sequences with null values. The Optional in the returned type is to handle the possibility that the sequence is empty.

The following is the code for the method:

```
  public final Optional<E> first() {
    Iterator<E> iterator = iterable.iterator();
    return iterator.hasNext()
        ? Optional.of(iterator.next())
        : Optional.<E>absent();
  }
```

Note that `Optional.of` will throw a NPE if the provided object is null.

P.S. Returning a Optional.absent() for the case where the first element is null would make the result indistinguishable from the empty sequence case, and this might be a problem.